# Object Orientation Menu

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm still having trouble with this project. I keep getting a 'cannot find symbol' in my third method and its on the 'Footballer PlayerIn[]' part! If you's could help me out it would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my code:

```
public static int addOne(String theArray[], int place, String theName, int noOfValues)  

{

 int step;

 if (noOfValues == 0)
    {
        theArray [0] = theName;
        noOfValues ++;  
    }
 else
    {                   
        for (step = noOfValues - 1 ; step >= place; step --)
            {
               theArray[step + 1] = theArray[step] ; 
            }
        theArray[place] = theName;          
        noOfValues ++;
    }

return noOfValues;
}


public static int findPlace(String theArray[], String theName, int noOfValues)  

{

        int step; 
        int place;


     step = 0 ;
     while ((step < noOfValues) && (theName.compareTo(theArray[step]) > 0))
            {
                step ++;
            }
        place = step ;   // Holds the correct location of place 
        return place;    // method must return an int

}

public static void listAll(Footballer PlayerIn[], int noOfValues)//displays array contents
{
    int index;

    for(index =0; index <noOfValues; index++)
    {
        System.out.print(PlayerIn[index]);
    }
}

public static void menu()

{
    System.out.println("    Menu    ");
    System.out.println(" ----------   ");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("  1. Add    ");
    System.out.println("  2. Delete ");
    System.out.println("  3. List All ");
    System.out.println("  4. Exit   ");

}


public static void options()

{

char options;


System.out.println();
System.out.print("Enter Option Required (1-4) ");
options = EasyIn.getChar(); 
while (options != '4')
{

        switch(options) 
            {
                case '1': System.out.println("Add Name");
                          EasyIn.pause();
                          break;
                case '2': System.out.println("Delete Name");
                          EasyIn.pause();
                          break;
                case '3': System.out.println("List All");
                          EasyIn.pause();
                          break;
                default:  System.out.println("Invalid Option!");
                          EasyIn.pause();
            }


    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Enter Option Required (1-4) ");
    options = EasyIn.getChar();
}
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args)

{
    menu();
    options();

}
```

}

Comment: Can you post whereyou used the listAll() method and what did you pass in the parameter

Comment: @kolossus It does when I comment out the third method. But it says 'cannot find symbol' and its on the 'Footballer PlayerIn[]' part

Comment: Show the full stacktrace

Comment: @kolossus What do you mean 'stacktrace'

Comment: Means the entirety of the exception message you received; Where you got *cannot find symbol*

Comment: Is `PlayerIn` a class?

Comment: The class is FootballerUse14 @Braj

Comment: Do you have `Footballer` class?

Comment: If the class is `FootballerUse14`, then that is what you have to call it, in variable declarations, not just `Footballer`.  Change `Footballer` to `FootballerUse14` inside the parentheses in the first line of `listAll`.

Comment: @kolossus - there's no stack trace.  This is a compile error.

Comment: Looks like you need to import `Fooballer` class.

Comment: @Braj - expressing your dissatisfaction with an answer is what downvotes and flags are for.  I wish you hadn't bullied Rod into deleting his answer; there was useful information in it.

Comment: I apologize for this. I am really Sorry @Rod_Algonquin

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void listAll(Footballer[] footballers) {
    // displays array contents
    for (Footballer footballer : footballers) {
        System.out.print(footballer);
    }
}
```

Work with the language.  You're trying to program Java like it is C.  You don't have to work that hard...

For example, all arrays have a member (because they are sort of like objects)

```
Footballer[] footballers = ...;
int arraySize = footballers.length;
```

And the "for each" loop operator makes walking an entire array a breeze

```
for (Footballer footballer : footballers) {
  ...
}
```

Also, it looks like your code is "add in place" manipulation of an Array.  You don't do that in general because your array won't grow, so you will lose the last element (or overflow).  In Java, you approach this with a `List`.  Use `ArrayList` which is a `List` where the storage is a resize-able array that does the malloc and copy when it runs out of space.

```
List<Footballer> footballers = ...;
footballers.add(5, new Footballer("Tom the Leg"));
```

Now that you have an add-at-index operation, just keep in mind that List's means of getting it's length is unfortunately named differently, it's `footballers.size()`